# install OSQA using xampp on windows 7

Tags: python, xampp, osqa

can anyone tell me that how can i install osqa on windows 7 with xampp localhost ? i don't know xampp support python.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're flexible about xampp, try bitnami native installer:
`http://bitnami.org/stack/osqa`

It took me about 10min for the installer to run, then I had running on Win7 localhost.